# CodeIgniter Undefined property when I call the function model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

please I need help, I'm looking for the mistake from 1 day ago

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Login::$Usuario_model
Filename: api/login.php
Line Number: 27

Fatal error: Call to a member function obtener_usuario() on a non-object in /home/fpincheira/web/cobranza/application/controllers/api/login.php on line 27
```

this is my model **usuario_model.php**. This query is a example, my real query is other

```
<?php
  class Usuario_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->db1 = $this->load->database('db1', TRUE);
    }

    function obtener_usuario($rut){
      $sql = "SELECT sysdate FROM dual"; //this is a example query
      $query = $this->db1->query($sql, array($rut));
      return $query->result_array();
    }
  }
?>
```

The controller **login.php**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
  class Login extends REST_Controller {

    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    }

    function validarUsuario_post(){
      try{
        $username = $this->post('user');

        $this->load->model('Usuario_model','usuario');
        $perfil_usuario = $this->usuario->obtener_usuario($username);
        //print_r($perfil_usuario);
      }catch(Exception $e){
        $this->response(array('error'=>$e->getMessage()), $e->getCode());
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

In my **autoload.php** I have loaded 'database' library.

Can you see the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer the question.

I had to create the object, because to import the model codeigniter not create the instance the object.

```
$this->load->model('usuario_model');
$usuario = new usuario_model();

$perfil_usuario = $usuario->obtener_usuario($username);
```

this way I could access to function of model.

**If somebody have a best answer, pliss comment, thanks**

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You need replace the following lines :

```
$this->load->model('Usuario_model','usuario');
$perfil_usuario = $this->usuario->obtener_usuario($username);
```

with :

```
$this->load->model('usuario_model');
$perfil_usuario = $this->usuario_model->obtener_usuario($username);
```

Try and let me know by commenting.

Comment: have you heard about `Loading with an alias`

Answer (score 0):

usuario_model.php and $this->load->model('Usuario_model','usuario'); Don't you think lowercase and uppercase model name is making difference. While calling to load model from controller U is in caps but actual model filename is in lowercase. So, model file is missing/not found.

are you getting $username value in controller? this link should help read the question part. [include function used before CodeIgniter class changes the view loading order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349900/include-function-used-before-codeigniter-class-changes-the-view-loading-order)

Comment: I change all uppercase U in my model and controller.
class usuario_model extends CI_Model
$this->load->model('usuario_model','usuario');
$perfil_usuario = $this->usuario->obtener_usuario($username);

and yet the error continue

Comment: are you getting $username value in controller/

Comment: yes, $this->post('user') is equal to '11111111', but I solve the error, but I dont know how close this Question and post the solution.