# Undefined property when calling function from model

Tags: php, codeigniter, object

When I try and load a Model, I get no issues. The code is as follows (in controller):

`applications/controllers/shortlinks.php`:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("logged");
    $this->load->model("shortlinks_logic"); //This model I'm interested in
}
```

As example, the `shortlinks_logic` model has this code in:

`applications/models/shortlinks_logic.php`

```
class Shortlinks_logic extends CI_Model {

    public function test() {
        echo "TEST";
    }

}
```

No issues there either. However, when I try and call this function in the controller:

```
public function something($argument_one, $argument_two) {
    $this->shortlinks_logic->test(); //Line 35 of following error
}
```

I get this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Shortlinks::$shortlinks_logic
>
> Filename: controllers/shortlinks.php
>
> Line Number: 35
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on a non-object in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\tools_v2\application\controllers\shortlinks.php** on line 35

I scouted StackOverflow, eventually coming to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25532393/2471423), but I realized I don't want to this for every function of my controller and I shouldn't have to add

```
$logic = new shortlinks_logic();
```

and call everything by

```
$logic->function();
```

because I know I can give the model an alias on load anyway

```
$this->load->model("shortlinks_logic", "logic");
```

and use

```
$this->logic->test();
```

**Is there a reason why I need to create a new object in each function and is there a way to fix this?**

I know I can autoload all the models which is an option, but I wanted to avoid this if possible, as not everyone will have access to all models and there are quite a few models, so I want certain models to go to certain users (hence why I want to load inside the controller).

I understand this is quite lengthy (apologies) so I bolded question.

Comment: What is exactly at C:\xampp\htdocs\tools_v2\application\controllers\shortlinks.php on line 35 1?

Comment: Sorry, I'll update the post to reflect what line it is, but it is: `$this->shortlinks_logic->test();` inside of the `something()` controller function. @AfghanWiz

Comment: If the model has no constructor method specified, the parent class constructor is called, so there is no reason to define an empty constructor in the model and calling `parent::__construct();`...

Comment: I've added `public function __construct() { parent::__construct();}` inside the model, but still same error. @shadyyx

Comment: Yes, this is what I have said - it is completely useless piece of code in this case. Without this `public function __construct() { parent::__construct();}` the parent class `__construct()` will be called anyway.

Comment: There is no `__construct()` function in the model either, just the controller. @shadyyx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was to this.

For some reason, it wasn't allowing me to load

```
$this->load->library("logged");
```

before

```
$this->load->model("shortlinks_logic");
```

I had to load the model first.

eg:

```
$this->load->model("shortlinks_logic");
$this->load->library("logged");
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code and working perfectly :-
created filname `shortlinks_logic.php` of model file under `application/models`

```
class Shortlinks_logic extends CI_Model {
    public function test() {
        echo "TEST";
    }
}
```

my controller `shortlinks.php`

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Shortlinks extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("shortlinks_logic"); 
  }
  public function something() {
    $this->shortlinks_logic->test(); 
  }
}
```

and you will get working perfectly.

Comment: My model is inside `applications/models`.

Comment: and model filename is same i given

Comment: Your new edit reflects exactly how my code is at the moment. It doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your model not load properly...

try this:

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->load->library("logged");
    $this->load->model("shortlinks_logic");
    parent::__construct();
}
```